# BWidget and Tile (ttk)

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tile, bwidget

Do any tcl'ers out there know what is happening with the (possible) transition of BWidget to use the newer Tile (ttk) themed widgets. I know that **some** work has been done in BWidget 1.8 (it does have the Widget::theme command after all), but if I try to "force" BWidget to use themed widgets, it fails for even the simplest scripts....

```
> tclsh85
% package require Tk
8.5.2
% package require tile
0.8.2
% namespace import -force ttk::*
% package require BWidget
1.8
% Widget::theme 1
1
%
% ButtonBox .buttons
unknown option "-padx"
% Dialog .dialog
can't access "ButtonBox::opt": parent namespace doesn't exist
```

etc, etc.

Comment: I think you're more likely to get an answer to this at http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.tcl/topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never do that namespace import since
ttk is not directly compatible to tk so it is unlikely
to work in any existing code.

The limited support that exist is the one you get with:

Widget::theme 1

It seems MainFrame and StatusBar is updated but
not much else in BWidget.